# Error in smtp connection when sending email

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

I have this simple program that sends an email to the email address given by the user, it works perfect on my pc, but when I try to run the same code on a pc at my job it doesn't work, it just keeps trying to connect and then comes the message

> Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte
>   conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo

Which is something like this:

> An error occurred during the connection attempt as the connected party
>   did not respond properly after a period of time

The error comes when I call the method Send(mailmessage), I'm pretty sure it's not a code problem, as it works fine on my pc, I think it's some kind of network configuration but network manager told my boss that I can use the port (587) and have no firewall restrictions, so I don't know what else to try, thanks for your answers...

I don't know if this useful but I'm currently connected via TeamViewer to a PC at my job that is also connected via remote desktop to another pc there, also working with C# in a visual studio (.net) project

Comment: It sounds like a network problem. Maybe you can ask that network manager if he can monitor the traffic and see if it is being blocked somewhere along the way.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I'm considering it as my last option as in this moment is kind of complicated to work together (since we're all doing home office) so I wanna try everything I can as a simply programmer

Comment: You can use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to see if the traffic is leaving your computer.

Comment: I have no privileges in that PC because of their politics, I just wanna know if there's a way to be 100% sure that it's a network problem or if there's still something that I can make

Comment: It is definitely not a code problem.

Comment: You cannot run at  work.  At work you are one a corporate network that has port 587 blocked to prevent attacks on the Outlook Server your corporation is using.  When you connect to your companies Outlook Server you are going through a proxy server to make the connection.  The proxy server will not allow you to connect to an outside smpt mail server on the same port number.

Comment: Just as a dumb question, if I'm not able to use the port, this could be solved by sending email using gmail api instead?